# Net6 Json Source Generator Ignore Model Property

Tags: c#, system.text.json, .net-6.0, sourcegenerators

I'm trying to combine the new NET6 JSON source generation with minimal APIs to try and maximize performance. I have a Model I'm trying to use with Source Generation that must include a referenced property from this library: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite`

I'm getting this error from the Library:

```
Error   CS0122  'Geometry.SortIndexValue' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

**I'd like to just ignore the entire property and not have it be included in the source generation. Is that possible?**

My Minimal API code looks like the following:
https://github.com/aherrick/Net6JsonSourceGenerator

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var app = builder.Build();

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.AddContext<VenueJsonContext>();
});

app.MapGet("GetVenues", () =>
{
    var venues = new List<Venue>();

    return venues;
});

app.Run();

public class Venue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore] // don't even include this property in source generation ideally.
    public Geometry Location { get; set; }
}

[JsonSerializable(typeof(Venue[]))]
public partial class VenueJsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to ignore properties/fields @aherrick?